# Java array: Difference between Component and Element

Tags: java, arrays, abstract-syntax-tree

I am reading the [API](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTNode.html) for the class `ArrayType`, a subclass of `ASTNode`.

There is a method `getComponentType()` and a method `getElementType()`.

For the `Statement`: `int[] list = new int[50]`, both the afformentioned methods return the type - `int`.

Does anyone know the difference between these two methods might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Javadoc has a table with brief descriptions, but you have to scroll down to read the full explanations. For `getComponentType()`, it says:

> Returns the component type of this array type. The component type may be another array type.

whereas for `getElementType()`, it says:

> Returns the element type of this array type. The element type is never an array type.
>
> This is a convenience method that descends a chain of nested array types until it reaches a non-array type.

So, for example, an `int[][]` would have a "component type" of `int[]`, but an "element type" of `int`.

Comment: ? Can you explain why `int[][]` would have a component type of `int[]`?

Comment: @Imray: That's just how arrays work in Java. Java doesn't have a distinct notion of "two-dimensional array"; it just has arrays of arrays, with a little bit of syntactic sugar to make them nicer to work with. An `int[][]` is just an array of `int[]`.

Comment: Thank you! Well explained :)